Problem fitting LMM to swaptions
I don't know what I am doing wrong.
My goal is to calibrate correlations between my brownian motions. For that I simulate forwards paths and then calculate Swaptions rates.
I use Euler Method to simulate my forwards rates.
Once done, I need to substract my convecutive forward multiplied by their rank to have a correct fit and I don't understand why.
It looks like some kind of convexity adjustement is needed to fit bbg volatility.
But my understanding is that the LMM is supposed to put the forwards in the correct measure.
Do any of you already came accross this problem?
